# Doxygen expands environment variable inside mainpage

Tags: doxygen

I have a `mainpage.dox` file which is invoked in the configuration file as:

`USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = ../mainpage.dox`

Inside the document I provide instructions on compiling. I would like to list the compiler option as `-L/$(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64 -lmkl_rt`, however the `$(MKLROOT)` part is expanded. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I put the following in mainpage.md

```
1 Test with backticks `-L$(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64 -lmkl_rt`

2 Test without backticks -L\$(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64 -lmkl_rt 

3 Test with code <code>-L\$(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64 -lmkl_rt</code>
@verbatim
4 Test with verbatim -L$(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64 -lmkl_rt
@endverbatim
```

The `$(MKLROOT)` in the first example gets (incorrectly) expanded.
The other three examples work as expected (using doxygen 1.8.5)

Note that `USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE` expects a pure markdown file, not something with a /*! .. */ comment block.

Comment: Putting a `\ ` in front of the `$` does not prevent expansion for me. `@verbatim` and `@endverbatim` are written out in the text and the variable is still expanded. I should mention that I have this variable inside single quotes.

Comment: @OSE I hade the same problem in Doxygen 1.8.8. The only thing that worked for me was `<code>\$...</code>`.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW the latest version of Doxygen as of this writing (1.8.15) still behave in the same way and escaping the backslash still doesn't work. I'm using the following workaround for now:

```
`-L$``$(MKLROOT)`
```

which, while ugly, works and doesn't require adding the `<code>` tags everywhere.

I've also created [an issue](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7073) in Doxygen asking for this to be changed.